# Infinite loop on a non-macro token

Tags: loops, catcodes

The following document infinite-loops:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\allowbreaks}[2][,]{\begingroup
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \scantokens{%
    \edef#1{%
      \show\detokenize{#1}%
      \detokenize{#1}%
      \noexpand\allowbreak
    \show0%
    }%
    #2%
  }
\endgroup}

\allowbreaks{$,$}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX displays

```
> the character ,.
,->\show ,
          ,\allowbreak \show 0
l.113 \allowbreaks{$,$}

?
```

repeatedly.

If I type `I\show` into it's prompt, it gives me

```
> the character ,.
,->\show ,,
           \allowbreak \show 0
l.113 \allowbreaks{$,$}
```

That is, the token that it's expanding it a character, not a macro.  How is this possible?

If I comment out the `breqn` line, it works fine.  I'm using 
pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian).

Comment: It runs without error with my texlive 2010 installation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say `\detokenize{,}`, the comma becomes a character of category code 12, so `\show,` will show the meaning of this character.

The `\edef` will define the active comma to expand to

```
\show,,\allowbreak\show0
```

where the two commas have category code 12.

But when `breqn` is loaded, the comma has mathcode `"8000` and you *are* in math mode! So TeX follows its rules: after having shown the meaning of the comma it finds another comma and, having it category code 12 and mathcode `"8000`, TeX replaces it with the meaning it currently has as an active character. That is, to show the comma and to use a comma, which has category code 12 and mathcode `"8000` …

Oops, infinite loop. `:-)`

Comment: you should mention that to "disable" the comma, its mathcode should be set to the value before `breqn` is loaded. Either with `\mathcode\`\,=...,` or with `\mathchar\`\,`.